# How to get Date Difference in textbox?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have two textboxes : TextBox1 and TextBox2 both have date.

I want to get date difference in third textbox, that is TextBox3.

My code is:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox3.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString());
}

protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox3.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you please stop close-voting every question for no reason? From the headline and the code sample it is pretty clear what the OP is asking!

Comment: Yes this is a clear and simple question. Is probably a duplicate but that's another matter.

Comment: *How can this be marked **off topic**?!?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime d1 = TextBox1.Text!=string.Empty?Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text): DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime d2 = TextBox2.Text!=string.Empty?Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text):DateTime.MinValue;
TimeSpan tspan= d2-d1;
TextBox3.Text = tspan.TotalDays.ToString();
```

Comment: I am unable to get value in textbox3. pls help me

Comment: What's the problem? *I am unable* is not a proper description.

Answer (score 3):

Convert both input values to `DateTime`, as in

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
```

Then, subtract both to get a `TimeSpan` object:

```
TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;
```

Then you can use the properties of `ts` to set the value of the third text box:

```
TextBox3.Text = ts.TotalDays.ToString();
```

I assume here that valid dates are input into both text boxes, otherwise you'll get an exception in the first line above. You can alternatively look into the `ParseExact` or `TryParse/TryParseExact` methods provided by the `DateTime` class.

Comment: I am unable to get value in textbox3. pls help me

Comment: I did - what additional problem do you have? *I am unable* is not a proper description.

Comment: Can you explain this solution in details

Comment: I'm not sure what else I could explain? Convert the input to `DateTime`, create a `TimeSpan` by subtracting one from the other and then show one of the values of the span... You could explain what you're doing: Show the most recent code in your question. Which values did you enter into the text fields? Do you get the word `null` or the number `0`? What happens when you enter two dates that differ a lot?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text);
TimeSpan span = d2-d1;
TextBox3.Text = span.TotalDays.ToString();
```

Comment: I am unable to get value in textbox3. pls help me

Comment: What's the problem? *I am unable* is not a proper description.